Error: ELF error: Failed to parse ELF file
Hello i am following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P22z9n1np9A&list=PL53JxaGwWUqCr3xm4qvqbgpJ4Xbs4lCs7&index=4
and he going through standard hello world program from solana git
https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld
but when i run solana program deploy dist/program/helloworld.so command i am getting this error Error: ELF error: ELF error: Failed to parse ELF file: Section or symbol name .data.ZN12wasmis longer than16 bytes . The error I'm getting indicates that the function is using too much stack i figured that but my knowledge in rust and solana is still minimum so i dont know how to fix it,or dont know how to find problematic function.
this is my Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "solana-bpf-helloworld"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "Example template program written in Rust"
authors = ["Solana Maintainers <maintainers@solana.com>"]
repository = "https://github.com/solana-labs/solana"
license = "Apache-2.0"
homepage = "https://solana.com/"
edition = "2018"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []

[dependencies]
borsh = "0.9.3"
borsh-derive = "0.10.0"
solana-program = "~1.10.35"
getrandom = { version = "0.2.2", features = ["custom"] }

[dev-dependencies]
solana-program-test = "~1.10.35"
solana-sdk = "~1.10.35"

[lib]
name = "helloworld"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

[profile.release]
lto = true


Something must have gone pretty wrong in the build for a wasm section to appear... try to do a clean build, since everything looks correct from here!
